# validates_associated - what is it really good for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, models

I have read the source code of several Rails apps but have never seen this method in use. Also, the documentation isn't particularly clear on when to use it.

EDIT: Have **you** used validates_associated in your projects? What were the use cases?